# Building a runnable jar BY DOUBLE CLICK using maven

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to build a JAR file that is runnable by simply double clicking it.

No need to open the `cmd` and write `java -jar jar-s-name.jar` and start it.

Is this possible ?

Is it possible to double click a JAR that will open a console and do what it should and disappear ?

I'm using MAVEN btw. this is the pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Excel</groupId>
  <artifactId>Export</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>
                                        OpenHR.RetrieveDataBySQLQuery
                                    </mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

JUST SOME DEPENDENCIES
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What you asked has nothing to do with Maven or Java. What you just asked was: 'How do I use my operating system?' I think this question should get closed.

Answer (score -1):

This kind of behavior is dictated by the OS.

Users must tell to the OS how to open JAR files. e.g. in Windows `Right Click ->  Properties -> Change -> C:\Program Files\Java\jreX\bin\javaw.exe`

In addition to this, Maven is mainly used to describe dependencies between modules. So it's not the right tool.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. so i understand that maven is not the took to make a runnable JAR. but i think it is doable without touching the OS because i downloaded many JARs that are runnables and many others that aren't.
point is, a runnable JAR should be possible. i just don't know how.

Answer (score -2):

Double clicking will always execute what your system suggests. Even if u handle to do so on your system, if you share your project on another system it wont be able to handle it the same way.

I would recommend you to write a script to start the jar file and thus start the script by double clicking instead of the .jar itself.

This script will depend on your system, for windows it could be a batch file, where you just sum up all of your commands that need to be executed, like

```
cd "navigate/to/my/folder"
java -jar jar-s-name.jar
```

Write that into a .txt file and save that file then as .bat file.

Thats quite the magic. You Maven already created an executable jar if you can execute it via console.

Even if not related to the problem, please still take in consideration that running a .jar always needs an installed Java version. Without Java the target system wont be able to to run your .jar aswell.